# AWS CLI identify all filesystems on a given EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

Is there a CLI option to list all filesystems for a given EC2? describe-instances doesn't seem to list all the file systems. I need the actual name, For example /home and /tmp from the following list

```
...
/dev/mapper/system-home    244810132    516152 131102056     1%      46 2448101274    0%   /home
/dev/xvdf   976557744 220587076 755768376    23%  162657 9765414783    0%   /tmp
...
```

Comment: Filesystems are a property of the operating system on the virtual computer. It is not related to the use of Amazon EC2, unless you are wanting to obtain a list of the Amazon EBS volumes (which are virtual disks) that are attached to the EC2 instance. Therefore, use a Linux command rather than an AWS CLI command.

Comment: @john-rotenstein I don't have access to ssh to the systems. But have permissions to run AWS CLI for the accounts. So what I am trying to get is all file systems on all EC2s in a account and correlate them with Cloudwatch alarm configuration to ensure each file system is being monitored for utilization. For that I need to know the name of each filesyste,

Comment: This is not possible without having access to the instances themselves. The filesystem is a property of the Operating System, which requires permission to either login to the instance, or at least the ability to create scripts on the instance to capture information. It's like me saying I'd like to track utilization on your own personal computer -- I can't see anything on your disk unless I can actually log into your computer.